# JavaScript: How to filter an array of nested objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like such

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: '123',
    book: {isNew: true}
  },
  {
    id: '123',
    book: {isNew: false}
  },
  {
    id: '123',
    book: {isNew: false}
  },
  {
    id: '123',
    book: {isNew: true}
  },
]
```

I am tring to filter the array to return only the objects where the book object has isNew as true.

I was attempting to something like this

```
arr.filter(obj => {
  // Use a forEach to determine which book obj is new
}
```

However a forEach can't return any values.

**EDIT**

Seems like my original way of explaining was a bit lacking.

Within each obj of the array, there can be multiple "Book" objects. All with dynamic keys. I want the object with at least one "Book" object that is new.

For example:

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: '123',
    book1242: {isNew: true},
    book9023: {isNew: false},
  },
  {
    id: '123',
    book0374: {isNew: false},
    book9423: {isNew: false},
  },
  {
    id: '123',
    book8423: {isNew: false},
    book9023: {isNew: false},
  },
  {
    id: '123',
    book6534: {isNew: true},
    book9313: {isNew: false},
  },
]
```

So my filtered array will consist of the first and last element of the original array

Comment: You don't need to use `forEach`. You have the object in `obj`. Test `obj.book.isNew`.

Comment: these Array methods do the forEaching for you. just supply the specific, individual object, filter.

Comment: I forgot the mention the book obj was just an example. In my project the key for the object is dynamic

Answer (score 1):

How about something like that

```js
arr.filter(({ book: { isNew } }) => isNew)
```

I'm just using a data structure to get the **isNew** property and return the TRUE value only

### UPDATE :

the **({ book: { isNew } })** it's just another way to write

```js
arr.filter((object) => object.book.isNew)
```

### UPDATE :

The question was about dynamic [key] I came with 2 solution
1 -

```js
arr.filter((item) => {
  for (const key of Object.keys(item)) {
    const { isNew } = item[key]
    if (typeof isNew === 'boolean') return isNew
  }
})
```

Where I'm filtering and looping for each key and checking if there is a property with key [ isNew ] 
if there is any will return it

Another way to write it

```js
arr.filter((item) => {
  for (const key of Object.keys(item))
    if (item[key].hasOwnProperty('isNew')) return item[key].isNew
})
```

Comment: Yes that would work, but I did a bad job asking my question. The book object was just an example. In my project, that object is dynamic, so I can't just target book. And there might be multiple "books" per obj. So something like 

{
  id: 123,
  key1: {isNew: true}
  key2: {isNew: false}
}

Comment: @Lemnns  Oh it's okay, You can do something like 

Which I don't really like it
```js
arr.filter((item) => {
  for (const key of Object.keys(item))
    if (item[key].hasOwnProperty('isNew')) return item[key].isNew
})
```
of you can do something like 

```js
arr.filter((item) => {
  for (const key of Object.keys(item)) {
    const { isNew } = item[key]
    if (typeof isNew === 'boolean') return isNew
  }
})
```

Comment: @Lemnns I'll be updating my answer soon <3